# Windows 7 wireless connection settings

Tags: windows-7, wireless-access-point

I have wireless Internet connected to my PC (windows 7, password protected) under a home network with three other laptops also connected to this group. In the evenings I want to take away the Internet connection from the laptops, is it possible to do this without turning the modem off every night and repeatedly changing the password?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Many routers provide that capability. If yours does not, and is compatible with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/), you can flash it to your router, and it provides very good [Access Restrictions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Access_Restrictions) that would fulfill your needs nicely.

For example, you could deny or filter internet access to a block of IP addresses or a set of MAC addresses. You could even do something like disable Facebook from 8pm to midnight on Tuesdays and Thursdays for only two of the computers connected to the router (wired or wireless).

**Edit:** You can check your router's compatibility with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) in their [Router Database](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database).

Comment: How does "flash it into your router" manifest? This sounds just like what I need, too, but I'd need a few more steps. +1

Comment: It depends on your router, as the method varies.  It could be as simple as uploading a file through your router's own upgrade function.  The first step would be to check [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/)'s [Router Database](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) for your router.

Comment: Also check out [TomatoUSB](http://tomatousb.org/), which has similar features but has a much more newbie-friendly interface.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer two solution :

1 -Connect your PC with network cable to Modem and in the evening remove Modem Antenna Or go to modem configuration and disable wireless function.

2 -Go to Modem Configuration and and enable firewall feature and set rule to prevent those ip addresses or computers to going out in that times of day -feature called scheduling in firewall rules-.